# JFrog Artifactory Cloud Configurate Remote Repository

Tags: maven, cloud, artifactory, nexus, remote-repository

I'm struggling with a simple test using JFrog Artifactory Cloud when creating a remote repository to adobe public one.

I configure a remote as maven repository, on URL I've inserted https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public and test ok on name just give a adobe-public name and click on save and finish.

After that I'm trying to obtain a existing (in repo.adobe.com) pom from https://xxxx/artifactory/adobe-public/com/day/jcr/vault/... but I can't get any pom.

I've tried to change several cache settings or offline settings but issue is always ""message" : "adobe-public: is offline". status 404.

On Logs, https://cccc/ui/admin/artifactory/advanced/system_logs there isn't also anything useful.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Root cause seems to be an issue with repository SSL certificate which is getting Artifactory to put the repository in offline mode: Failed retrieving resource from https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by global offline mode being active.

I had same issue.

Solved in: "https://.../ui/admin/artifactory/configuration/artifactory_general" - turn off "Global Offline Mode" and save.

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar setup with Maven repository pointing to https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public and was successfully able to download the pom files, refer the below snippet,

> $ wget --user=admin --password=Password https://myartifactory/artifactory/adobe-repo/ant/ant/1.5.1/ant-1.5.1.pom
> --2020-11-01 10:27:54--  https://myartifactory/artifactory/adobe-repo/ant/ant/1.5.1/ant-1.5.1.pom
> Resolving myartifactory (myartifactory)... 1.2.3.4, 2.1.3.5, 3.7.7.4
> Connecting to myartifactory (myartifactory)|1.2.3.6|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
> Authentication selected: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
> Reusing existing connection to myartifactory:443.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
> Length: 140 [application/x-maven-pom+xml]
> Saving to: ‘ant-1.5.1.pom’
> ant-1.5.1.pom             100%[====================================>]     140  --.-KB/s    in 0s
> 2020-11-01 10:27:59 (5.14 MB/s) - ‘ant-1.5.1.pom’ saved [140/140]

Use wget and try to download the file as I did. Also, the error "offline" says that the repository is offline and cannot be downloaded, goto to the repository's configuration page under Artifactory UI --> Admin --> Repositories | Adobe-public and under the Basic tab, scroll down and look for "offline", if this "offline" is checked, uncheck it and try again.